# How to bind linq data into Model class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have following query,

```
var userTree = (from user in users
join location in locations on user.FkHomeLocationId equals location.LocationId
join region in regions on location.RegionId equals region.LocationId
group region by new {
    Regionid = region.LocationId,
    location.LocationId
}
into grp
select new {
    RegionName = regions.FirstOrDefault(s = >s.LocationId == grp.Key.Regionid).LocationName,
    Branches = new {
        BranchName = locations.FirstOrDefault(b = >b.RegionId == grp.Key.Regionid).LocationName,
        Users = users.Where(u = >u.FkHomeLocationId == grp.Key.LocationId).Select(s = >new {
            FullName = s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName
        }).ToList()
    }
}).ToList();
```

I want to bind the query result into model. how can I do this. I created following class model to achieve that,

```
public class TreeModel
    {
        public string RegionName { get; set; }
        public Branch Branchs { get; set; }
    }

    public class Branch
    {
        public string BranchName { get; set; }
        public List<User> Users { get; set; }
    }

    public class User
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
    }
```

Now need to bind above query data into this model class? Have any best way to do this without creating `Branch` and `User` classes? because my application have another classes with the same name of User and Branch and I feel some guilty to create separate classes like this for query data binding? I'm I correct?

**Updated: I tried as follows,**

```
var userTree = (from user in users
join location in locations on user.FkHomeLocationId equals location.LocationId
join region in regions on location.RegionId equals region.LocationId
group region by new {
    Regionid = region.LocationId,
    location.LocationId
}
into grp
select new Application.Alerts.Models.AlertUserTreeViewModel() {
    RegionName = regions.FirstOrDefault(s = >s.LocationId == grp.Key.Regionid).LocationName,
    Branchs = new Application.Alerts.Models.Branch() {
        BranchName = locations.FirstOrDefault(b = >b.RegionId == grp.Key.Regionid).LocationName,
        Users = new Application.Alerts.Models.User {
            FirstName = users.Where(u = >u.FkHomeLocationId == grp.Key.LocationId).FirstOrDefault().FirstName
        }
    }
}).ToList();
```

But I'm getting compile error in this line,

```
Users = new Application.Alerts.Models.User {
    FirstName = users.Where(u = >u.FkHomeLocationId == grp.Key.LocationId).FirstOrDefault().FirstName
}
```

as

**Cannot implicitly convert type 'Alerts.Models.User' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Alerts.Models.User>'**

Comment: Erm.. whut? You already did create Branch and User classes, so use them? `select new TreeModel {
    RegionName = ...`

Comment: @CaiusJard yes, i'm tried as this. but problem is how `Users = users.Where(u = >u.FkHomeLocationId == grp.Key.LocationId).Select(s = >new {
            FullName = s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName
        }).ToList()` this part do?

Comment: you have a List<TreeModel> therefore use userTree .FirstOrDefault() to get your model
about class: add constructor to TreeModel and this.Branchs = new Branch(). btw its not a good practice to make name and type same

Comment: @PowerMouse How can I bind query data into model?

Comment: 1. you have a list of TreeModel objects.
2. insead of select new {... make: select new TreeModel{ RegionName = ...}

Comment: @PowerMouse can u please my updated question sir

Comment: it expects LIST of Users
should be Users = new List<User>(){new User(){.......}}

Answer (score 2):

just add extra FirstName property to your anonymous classes

```
var userTree = 
....
select new {
    RegionName = ...
    Branches = new {
        BranchName = ...,
        Users = ....Select(s = >new {
            FirstName=s.FirstName,
            FullName = s.FirstName + " " + s.LastName
        }).ToList()
    }
```

after this you can create view model

```
var treeModel= userTree.Select( new TreeModel {
                RegionName = userTree.RegionName
                Branchs =userTree.Branches.Select(i=> 
                new Branch { 
                 BranchName= i.BranchName,
                 Users= i.Users.Select(j=> new User{ FirstName=j.Firstname})
                )});
```

if you need only fullname in your  userTree you can convert back

```
userTree= userTree.Select( new TreeModel {
                RegionName = userTree.RegionName
                Branchs =userTree.Branches.Select(i=> 
                new Branch { 
                 BranchName= i.BranchName,
                 Users= i.Users.Select( j=> new {j.FullName})
                )});
```

UPDATE

if you want to run another query using dbcontext you can try this

```
var userTree = (from user in users
join location in locations on user.FkHomeLocationId equals location.LocationId
join region in regions on location.RegionId equals region.LocationId
group region by new {
    Regionid = region.LocationId,
    location.LocationId
}
into grp
select new Application.Alerts.Models.AlertUserTreeViewModel {
    RegionName = regions.FirstOrDefault(s = >s.LocationId == grp.Key.Regionid).LocationName,
    Branches = new new Application.Alerts.Models.Branch {
         BranchId = locations.FirstOrDefault(b = >b.RegionId == 
        grp.Key.Regionid).LocationId,
        BranchName = locations.FirstOrDefault(b = >b.RegionId == grp.Key.Regionid).LocationName,
        Users = users.Where(u = >u.FkHomeLocationId == grp.Key.LocationId).Select(s = >new  User {
             Id=s.Id,
             LastName=s.LastName,
            FirstName= s.FirstName 
        }).ToList()
    }
}).ToList();
```

Comment: I updated my answer. Try it and let me know

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<<anonymous type: string FirstName>>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Administration.Application.Alerts.Models.User>` this error showing

Comment: @Rooter Sorry again. Use  new User {} instead.  I updated my answer. Since the are 2 different users it is confusing.

Comment: If I add additional properties for  Branch class as BranchId  and LastName,UserId for user class, how should I change the code for assign value for those

Comment: @Rooter I updated my answer. Check again.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Branch` has a `List<User>` but you are trying to instantiate as a `User` that's why you are getting the error. Use below code.

```
Users = users.Where(u = >u.FkHomeLocationId == grp.Key.LocationId).Select(u => new User { FirstName = u.FirstName }).ToList()
```

Comment: @How get last name and assign it into fullname property?

Comment: @Rooter Please check the updated code. You can assign any property using the lambda expression in the Select() method.

Comment: If I add additional properties for  Branch class as BranchId  and LastName,UserId for user class, how should I change the code for assign value for those

Comment: In the just add more properties. i.e new User { FirstName = u.FirstName, LastName = u.LastName, UserId= u.UserId }